# How to perform jquery each function on ajax loaded content?

Tags: jquery, iframe, each

I'm trying to add some code to an older site that uses jQuery. The purpose of the code is to add the autoplay, loop, and mute variables to the src of a  Vimeo iframe (when the video is meant to be displayed like an animated gif). I have achieved this successfully on another site, but the issue I'm having with this site is that the pages are loaded with ajax so I'm not able to target the iframes because they did not exist on the page originally.

Here's the code:

```
function vimeo_funtimes() {
    $('iframe').each(function( index ) {
        var vimeosrc = $(this).attr('src') + '?background=1&autoplay=1&loop=1&muted=1';
        $(this).attr('src', vimeosrc);
    }); 
}
```

This function is then called after the ajax content is loaded.

I found many posts noting that when this is a click event, it needs to be delegated. However, this is not a click event, it should just happen after the content loads, so I'm not sure if this can be done.

The example above is live here: isaidicanshout.com

As you can see none of the videos have the autoplay code attached.

Comment: Do you call `vimeo_funtimes()` in the success after the frames loaded? And if not, why not add the parameters BEFORE you load the iFrames? We need to seem more code and an object example

Comment: Just wrap in `$(function() { .... })` if this is done on load

Answer (score 0):

This is a very palm-to-forehead moment, but I was able to solve this by adding a setTimeout so that the function doesn't try to modify the videos until after the page has loaded.

```
function vimeo_funtimes() {
    setTimeout( function() {
        $('iframe').each(function( index ) {
            var vimeosrc = $(this).attr('src') + '?background=1&autoplay=1&loop=1&muted=1';
            $(this).attr('src', vimeosrc);
        }); 
    }, 500 )
}
```

Comment: Which is normally done like this
`$(function() { $('iframe').each(function( index ) { var vimeosrc = $(this).attr('src') + '?background=1&autoplay=1&loop=1&muted=1';  $(this).attr('src', vimeosrc);  }); })`